# Angularjs does not allow you to create ul recursively within li?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat, nested-lists

How can I create that deep structure with ng-repeat?
I'm having problems with tags that are automatically closed in this directive.

can anybody help me?

```
<ul>
    <li>A
        <ul>
            <li>B
                <ul>
                    <li>C
                       <ul><li>D</li></ul>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

here is the json code.

```
{"obj":[{"code":"0","name":"A"},{"code":"1","name":"B"},
    {"code":"2","name":"C"},{"code":"3","name":"D"}]}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you post what you have tried?

Comment: do a search for "angular recursive tree" and similar terms. Should find numerous results. Post what you currently have. Using `ng-if` and `ng-repeat` and some mapping of your data into nested structure with uniform child array names there shouldn't be any closing tag issues

Comment: The given examples have a different structure (http://benfoster.io/blog/angularjs-recursive-templates see this).  When I use template, I do not have a new array to read in there. is the same array. That's where I lose myself.

Comment: Map your data to match that structure

Comment: @charlietfl https://jsfiddle.net/elciospy/ps3xby70/10/

Comment: @luisenrike I posted more info.

Answer (score -1):

Here is my code

```
<script type="text/ng-template" id="categoryTree">
            <!-- {{ncm | json}} = { "tipo": "SECAO", "codigo": "XV", "nome": "METAIS COMUNS E SUAS OBRAS", "notas": [ 87 ] } -->
            {{ncm.codigo}}
            <ul>
                <li ng-include="'categoryTree'"></li>
            </ul>
</script>
<ul>   
    <li ng-repeat="ncm in vm.nomenclaturaList.ancestrais" ng-include="'categoryTree'" ng-hide="$first"></li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score -1):

Here is the code to verify

https://jsfiddle.net/elciospy/ps3xby70/10/

```
<script type="text/ng-template"  id="tree_item_renderer.html">
    {{data.name}}
    <ul>
        <li ng-repeat="data in data" ng-include="'tree_item_renderer.html'"></li>
    </ul>
</script>

<ul ng-controller="TreeController">
    <li ng-repeat="data in tree.obj" ng-include="'tree_item_renderer.html'"></li>
</ul>
```

controller

```
angular.module("myApp", []).
controller("TreeController", ['$scope', function($scope) {

    $scope.tree = {"obj":[{"code":"0","name":"A"},{"code":"1","name":"B"},
    {"code":"2","name":"C"},{"code":"3","name":"D"}]}
}]);
```